# Why does tkinter creating two windows here? And how can i stop it?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from subprocess import check_call



def copy_name():
    cmd = 'echo ' + name.strip() + '|clip'
    return check_call(cmd, shell=True)


root = tk.Toplevel(background="black")
root.title("Copying")
root.resizable(False, False)

T = tk.Label(root, text=name, height=2, width=len(name) + 25, background="black", foreground="white")
T.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Copy", command=copy_name, background="black", foreground="white")
button.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

This is my code.

I just wanted to test this way of copying text...

About my expectations... i want to understand from where those windows are appearing, and how to stop it.
Im just a newbie in Python and Tkinter... so please, tell me what i did wrong

Comment: Did you mean: `command=copy_name`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `Toplevel()`. You just wanted single window. Just replaced `Toplevel` to `tk()`

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from subprocess import check_call


def copy_name():
    cmd = 'echo ' + name.strip() + '|clip'
    return check_call(cmd, shell=True)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Copying")
root.resizable(False, False)

T = tk.Label(root, text='name', height=2, width=25, background="black", foreground="white")
T.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Copy", command=copy_name, background="black", foreground="white")
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every tkinter window requires a root window - an instance of `Tk`. If you don't create one, one will be created automatically. When you do `root = tk.Toplevel(background="black")`, tkinter will first create an instance of `Tk` and then it will create your `Toplevel`, resulting in two windows.

The solution in this case is to call `Tk` instead of `Toplevel`. Also, you'll need to remove the `background="black"` argument and instead configure the background in a separate step.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background="black")
```

Comment: So.... If i replace a 'TopLevel()' with 'Tk()' should it work?

Comment: @EmiliaZero: in this case, yes.

Comment: But it doesn't.

Comment: i did it even before adding a 'TopLevel()'

Comment: @EmiliaZero: it works for me. Though, you need to remove the `background` argument and instead call `root.configure(background="black")`.  Also, the code you posted doesn't define "name" so I had to do that as well.

Comment: thanks for your time and tips. I'll try to do something by myself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bryan said, you should forget about Toplevel(). The normal way is Tk().
Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label( root, text='Select:', background='green').pack(side='top')
btn1 = ttk.Button( root, text='Discard').pack()
btn2 = ttk.Button( root, text='Quit').pack()
while True:
  root.mainloop()
```

And you should get:
[image: Result]